# why is my wordpress Jquery-Ajax call not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello I'm currently developing a wordpress application. I have been able to accomplish almost everything the application needs. I was even able to use Jquery-Ajax to insert data into my custom database table and get a background feedback of the submission.

But where I'm stock right now is autopopulating my textfields based on a dropdown selection. I have read several articles online and the answer I saw here [Why is my AJAX call not working?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112998/why-is-my-ajax-call-not-working)  but I still can't fix the problem Below are my codes:

```
/* Fetching file from the database*/
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
function ajaxAutopopulate() {
    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['package'] ) ) {

        $birdday = $_REQUEST['package'];   // department day

        global $wpdb;
        // Let's take the data that was sent and do something with it
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT body_weight, daily_intake, fcr FROM bird_weight WHERE day=$birdday");

        $users_arr = array();

        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
            $bweight     = $result->body_weight;
            $dintake     = $result->daily_intake;
            $fcr         = $result->fcr;
            $users_arr[] = array("body_weight" => $bweight, "daily_intake" =>$dintake,"fcr"=>$fcr);
        }

        // encoding array to json format
        echo json_encode( $users_arr);

    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxAutopopulate', 'ajaxAutopopulate' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxAutopopulate', 'ajaxAutopopulate' ); 

//The Html Form on the frontend
echo
    '<form action="" name="mybirdweight" method="post">
        <div>
            <select id="days" name="days">
                <option value=" " > Select Your Bird Age</option>
                <option value="1"> 1</option>
                <option value="2"> 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Body Weight</p>
            <input id="bweight" type="text" name="bweight" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Daily Intake</p>
            <input id="dintake" type="text" name="dintake" value=""/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>FCR</p>
            <input id="fcr" type="text" name="fcr" value=""/>
        </div>
    </form>';

//Here is the jquery-ajax javascript

/* the jquery ajax request*/
echo <<< END
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // On change of the dropdown do the ajax
            jQuery("#days").change(function() {
                var package = jQuery(this).val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    // Change the link to the file you are using
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    // This just sends the value of the dropdown
                    data: {package: package},
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Parse the jSON that is returned
                        // Using conditions here would probably apply
                        // incase nothing is returned
                        var Vals =JSON.parse(response);
                        // These are the inputs that will populate
                        jQuery("input[name='bweight']").val(Vals.body_weight);
                        jQuery("input[name='dintake']").val(Vals.daily_intake);
                        jQuery("input[name='fcr']").val(Vals.fcr);

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
END;
```

Please where am I missing it?

Comment: Where is this code? Is this all actually together like this or in separate files?

Comment: Try select drop-down `jQuery("select#days").change(function(e)` and 
  `var package = jQuery('#days option:selected').val();` and check your ajax link if it called properly or not.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have tried it out as well but the auto-population is still not working

Comment: All the functions are located in the functions.php file. The database handling function is on its own, while the html form and the jquery-ajax javascript are on the same function inside the functions.php file. I'm using a child theme

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the data that you are sending in the ajax request.
For ajax to work in WordPress you need to send the **action** variable in ajax post request. 
Change

```
data: {package: package},
```

to

```
data: {action: 'ajaxAutopopulate',  package: package}
```

Also you can use the wordpress default function

```
wp_send_json( $response )
```

for encoding of data
and

```
 admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
```

for the ajax file url.

If you have your js code in a separate file , you may need to use

```
wp_localize_script
```

to pass the value to the js file

Comment: Thank you all very much let me try out your suggestions and get back to you

Comment: I have also tried your suggestion but it still didn't work

Comment: Can you please check what url the ajax is posting data. 
i think your ajax url is not correct . 
Add 
$ajax_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); 
before the line 
echo <<< END 
and then replace the line 
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
with
url: "{$ajax_url}", 

or try giving static url like 
http://localhost/practise/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
to make sure that the ajax is posting data to correct url

Also make sure that you are sending action variable in post data

data: {action: 'ajaxAutopopulate',  package: package}

Comment: or may be try adding  a alert in success function of ajax request

Comment: Thanks  for your answer but I have also tried it out and it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you please check what the http status of ajax request. is it returning 200 ok or 404 error.

Comment: Thanks  For your help, but I have given up on the ajax technique, I intend using php to do the application. Although I have not succeeded yet, but below is what I have done so far: global $wpdb;
       $day=$_POST['days'];
$myresults = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT body_weight, daily_intake, fcr FROM bird_weight WHERE day=$day");

Comment: global $wpdb;
       $day=$_POST['days'];
$myresults = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT body_weight, daily_intake, fcr FROM bird_weight WHERE day=$day");

 echo $myresults->body_weight;
    

echo <<< EOT
   <form action="" name="mybirdweight" method="post">
    <div>
    <p>Select Bird Age Below to Analyze Bird Weight </p>
    <select name="days" required >
    <option value=" " > Select Your Bird Age</option>
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>

Comment: I don't know if you can help with the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't successful with the jquery/Ajax autopopulate, so I have been able to get the Job done from the server side, using PHP to fetch the information I need to display, on form submission.